# XSS exploit from sub-domain to main domain

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies, xss

I am developing an application where i setup sub-domain for each user when they register.

So far, I am allowing user to create their page with some basic HTML page element, but i want to extend this option to allow them add javascript in their page.

Now, my concern is , Can user exploit another user or take over other user account using evil cookie logger or by performing an evil action form using javascript submit or by any other means ? Each "user javascript" will reside in different sub-domain.

**My Current Configuration :-**

1. Sessions are stored in database
2. Domain path is set to "/"
3. Domain name is set to null
4. Host Access Only is true
5. Http Access Only is true
6. Every forms has hidden csrk token

**Update :** I am also using FB login , Google Login oAuth. Do you suggest disabling my registration option and use only oAuth for such issues ?

Comment: The important configuration is your cors header.

Comment: If they access the same cookies, one could clone the **PHP SESSION** wich is a big security issue

Comment: I have not set up any `cors` setting and i believe , by default `Cross orgin access` is disabled. Am i right ?  On clone of PHP Session , i am using HTTP only and Host only method in cookie, which i believe will stop them in getting cookie via javascript , so ?